# How to deal with a "preferred user setting" and automatic fallback

Tags: gui-design, settings, optional-fields

**Context**

I'm adding a new option in a configuration screen. It's basically a simple radio-button / combobox / checkbox that either uses the default **Setting A** or the new **Setting B**.

**Setting A** is the current default setting and guaranteed to always work.

**Setting B** is a new setting that adds some additional functionality, but isn't always guaranteed to work.

*GUI example*:

[image]

A requirement is that if setting B doesn't work, that the system automatically uses setting A. I cannot detect beforehand if setting B will work unless the setting is saved and the system is rebooted (which takes about 10-20 seconds). This prohibits me of simply hiding the option if it's not relevant, or having some sort of "test setting" functionality.

**Question**: 
How do I make it clear that if setting B is selected, it might not work and/or will revert to setting A, BEFORE the user actually saves/reboots?

Comment: You could allow the user to select setting B and upon saving, explain the full effects of their choice in a popup, confirming that they'd like to continue under these conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the *principle of least surprise* it would be preferable to explain upfront, rather than "concern" the user by "raising a flag" on their choice.

Even with real estate limitations you may want to do something like:

---

> Preferences: following settings may be auto-adjusted by the system (i)
>
> Option C:
>
> Option D:

---

With the "(i)" explaining that system stability could require the values to be modified to some other logical configuration.

Another challenge with UI is to explain: *"last time you chose X but I (the system) had to override to Y"*.  One can leave this to users memory, but with [the Recognition rather than recall heuristic](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/recognition-and-recall/)  it is better UX not to do so.  Tagging the selection with "(prior setting)" is one UI soloution.

Answer (score 0):

### EDIT

In case you lack space and still want to draw the attention of the user, try having a ***"caution icon"*** like so:

[image: Caution icon]

This would make the user hover or click on it and the *tooltip* then provides the information

### General Scenario

Something like this should do the trick.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFMwZE.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: I thought an explanatory text would be a good idea, but there's isn't really enough room to explain it. Would a tooltip on setting B help, or would that be too hidden?

Comment: @DennisW - Edited my answer to cater your low on space scenario

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a radio option to select between setting A and B you could use a checkbox with only showing setting B stating that setting A will be used if it fails. This may require a bit more text to explain the default behavior (without more context it's difficult to say) but for an example:

[image: mockup]

I feel like the key word is "Experimental". It provides the idea that this could cause a failure, but the following text reassures the user that a failure will failover to a stable setting.

And if a third setting is added then maybe a radio to select the setting is the proper choice, and explaining that Setting A is used on failure above the radio options as other answers have explained. But if there's only ever the 1 extra option I think a simple checkbox should do the trick.